# JAVA formWindowClosed

Tags: java, swing, jframe

```
  this.setDefaultCloseOperation(this.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
    {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
      {
          new AddPatient().setVisible(false);
          new SearchPatient().setVisible(true);
      }
    });
```

Got a problem regards with code above. Is this the right way to trigger the dispose and at the same time setVisible of anothe JFrame?

Could someone tell me is that the right way to code it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
{
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
  {
      //open other frame
  }
});
```

Comment: what is that 'frame' sir drewmore?

Comment: where do I put that code? Am I going to put that on private void formWindowClosed Event?

Comment: `frame` is the `JFrame` you want to change the closing event for. I only included it for purposes of clarity - if you're calling this within the frame (as I'm supposing you are), you can simply call `this.addWindowListener...`. Does that answer your question? I'm not completely sure I understood it...

Comment: but I don't know what is the name of my JFrame where can I locate that one so that I can apply the codes that you gave to me. I'm working with JFrame Form.

Comment: Change `frame.addWindowListener...` to `this.addWindowListener...` and add it anywhere in the code for the JFrame class you want to do this with.

Comment: I got a tons of error after I put your codes and do what you just said... why is that?

Comment: Please edit your question with the updated code and the exact "error messages" you got.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27916/discussion-between-crystal-maiden-and-drewmore)